# How to target an attribute of a Dto, when mapping a List of entities to a List of dto entities, via an expression or custom method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, mapstruct, mapper

In my mapper class I have one mapper, which maps a single resource object to a resourceDto. Also in the resourceDto, I have an attribute called favoured which is mapped manually via the isResourceFavoured method.

I have another mapper which maps a List of resources to to a List of resourceDtos.

Now, I want for this method to have for each resourceDto the attribute favoured mapped, via a custom expression, like the isResourceFavoured method for the single resource to resourceDto method.

How would this be possible? Is the maybe a auto generated annotation, where resourceToResourceDto method for Lists uses the same method, but for single objects?

```java
@Mapping(target = "courseId", source = "resource.course.id")
@Mapping(target = "favoured", expression = "java(isResourceFavoured(resource, userId))")
public abstract ResourceDto resourceToResourceDto(Resource resource, Long userId);

@Mapping(target = "courseId", source = "course.id")
public abstract List<ResourceDto> resourceToResourceDto(List<Resource> resources);

public boolean isResourceFavoured(Resource resource, Long userId) {
    ApplicationUser user = userService.findApplicationUserById(userId);
    return resourceService.isFavoured(resource, user);
}
```

Comment: Does your ResourceDto have a property for the userId?

Comment: No, I pass the userId from the Endpoint via the authentication variable to the mapper

Answer (score 0):

When using mapping methods with multiple parameters such as `ResourceDto resourceToResourceDto(Resource, Long)` then collection mapping methods will not be able to use them. In order to simplify this you can use the `@Context` source parameters.

Using `@Context` tells MapStruct that those parameters should be passed as is to other mapping methods, lifecycle, object factory methods, etc.

In your example your mapper can look like:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class ResourceMapper {

    // Service injected somehow

    @Mapping(target = "courseId", source = "resource.course.id")
    @Mapping(target = "favoured", source = "resource")
    public abstract ResourceDto resourceToResourceDto(Resource resource, @Context Long userId);

    public abstract List<ResourceDto> resourceToResourceDto(List<Resource> resources, @Context Long userId);

    public boolean isResourceFavoured(Resource resource, @Context Long userId) {
        ApplicationUser user = userService.findApplicationUserById(userId);
        return resourceService.isFavoured(resource, user);
    }
}
```